# How to customise colours InAppSettingsKit?

Tags: ios, cocoa, inappsettingskit

Maybe I am missing something obvious, but it seems that the only way to change colours of the cells is to change the code in IASKAppSettingsViewController and/or IASKPSTextFieldSpecifierViewCell. Even that doesn't seem to work for everything.

I am using PSTextFieldSpecifier, PSToggleSwitchSpecifier and PSTitleValueSpecifier.

For PSTextFieldSpecifier, in

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

I added these two lines:

```
_textField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

However, that only changed the colours of values, not of titles. How do I change colours of titles?

Comment: Haven't tried myself but did you try customizing the colors using the UIAppearance API?

Comment: Wow! I've just tried it and it's so easy. Thanks!

Comment: But it didn't work for text colour of TextFields and labels in the table.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I used UIAppearance to set the background of the cells and then I added this:

```
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:122.0/255.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.000f];
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:122.0/255.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.000f];
```

to the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

of the IASKAppSettingsViewController.

Comment: sounds good. I'd advise subclassing `IASKAppSettingsViewController` to override `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Then you can easily update to newer versions of IASK.